# flask "ValueError: View function did not return a response" when write to json file

Tags: python, json, flask

hi guys below is my view from my flask application. When I am uploading file to my application it writes dictionary to json file which was indicated but in response it returns error that `""ValueError: View function did not return a response""`

```
@app.route('/')
def upload_file_mainpage():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_file = request.files['file']
        outfile = open('out.json', 'w')
        with outfile as outfile:
            return json.dump(soupla(new_file), outfile), 200
```

soupla returns dictionary I have no problem with that and even when I use `json.dumps(soupla(new_file))`  it returns exactly what I want. But I cannot write to file I used this [link](http://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) to write dictionary to the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to do two things. You want to write the data to a file, and you want to return that data in the response. To do both, you need to do two separate steps.

For example:

```
@app.route('/')
def upload_file_mainpage():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_file = request.files['file']
        rv = json.dumps(soupla(new_file))
        outfile = open('out.json', 'w')
        with outfile as outfile:
            outfile.write(rv)
        return rv, 200
```